# Gauss-Seidel algorithm, modify array in-place

Tags: numpy, in-place

I would like to implement the Gauss-Seidel algorithm.
The code below is not correct because the computation of U[i,j] must use the U[h,k] already calculated in the current iteration.

```
for k in xrange(s):
    U[1:nx, 1:ny] = (1 - 4*gamma)*U[1:nx, 1:ny] + gamma*(
                                            U[:nx-1, 1:ny]
                                          + U[2:, 1:ny]
                                          + U[1:nx, :ny-1]
                                          + U[1:nx, 2:])
```

Is it possible to modify in-place U[1:nx, 1:ny] ?
For instance, suppose we have the ufunc:
`f = lambda u, a, b, c, d: (1 - 4*gamma)*u + gamma*(a+b+c+d)`
Then, may be it would be possible to write something like that:

```
for k in xrange(1):
    f(U[1:nx, 1:ny], U[:nx-1, 1:ny], U[2:, 1:ny], U[1:nx, :ny-1], U[1:nx, 2:],
        out=U[1:nx, 1:ny])
```